# Custom Field does not return value

Tags: django, django-models

in a Django projet, I need to work wit GTIN then I've created a basic custom field which looks like:

```
class GTINField(models.CharField):
    description = _("GTIN Code")
    default_error_messages = {
        'blank': _('GTIN code is required.'),
        'invalid': _('Enter a valid GTIN code.'),
    }
    empty_strings_allowed = False
    default_validators = [validate_gtin]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 14
        super(GTINField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(GTINField, self).deconstruct()
        del kwargs["max_length"]
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

The validator is:

```
@deconstructible
class GTINValidator:
    message = _('Enter a valid gtin code.')
    code = 'invalid'

    def __call__(self, value):
        if not self._is_valid_code(value):
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)

    def _is_valid_code(self, code):
        if not code.isdigit():
            return False
        elif len(code) not in (8, 12, 13, 14):
            return False
        else:
            return int(code[-1]) == self._get_gtin_checksum(code[:-1])

    def _get_gtin_checksum(self, code):
        total = 0

        for (i, c) in enumerate(code):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                total = total + int(c)
            else:
                total = total + (3 * int(c))

        check_digit = (10 - (total % 10)) % 10
        return check_digit


validate_gtin = GTINValidator()
```

Now, I would like to format my field (remove "-" in the string) in the clean() method but I cannot get the field value, Pdb always returns

```
(Pdb) self.ean
<gtinfield.fields.GTINField>
```

Is there something that I've missed from [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/) ?

Comment: Please show exactly what you're doing in that final snippet. Is `self` a model instance? Show the full model and how you populated it.

Comment: there is noting special in my model, it contains ean = GTINField(), and I try to update the value in a save() override.

Comment: You really need to show all that code.